# How many Watts is my stereo?

Tags: audio, speakers, stereo

I have a Pioneer SX-316-S stereo. It has six speakers. The specification says it consumes 320 Watts.  It also says the continuous power output is 100W per channel. It also says the RMS power output is 144W per channel. When I advertise this thing, how many Watts can I call it? 320 Watts?  600 Watts? 864 Watts?

Comment: All of the above. It's your amplifier, you can call it whatever you want. Alternatively, you can use your own full description in the ad. That ought to be exhaustive enough.

Comment: Presumably you have 3 speakers in each channel?

Comment: It has 2 front speakers, 1 sub, 1 center, and 2 side speakers. I assume that means there are 6 channels.

Comment: @Andyaka I removed my answer, thanks for the insight.

Comment: I'd just quote Pioneer's specs, as that's what a buyer will use when comparing your stereo to another product.

Comment: If you're an engineer, you label it 100W per channel. If you're a marketing "professional" you label it "900 Thumping™ Watts - _Now With Electrolytes!_"

Comment: For what it's worth, you can see the specs at: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/260358/Pioneer-Sx-316-S.html?page=29#manual I don't see a claim of 144 Watts, only 130 (though that's not a major difference)--and even that's at 10% THD, which is a pretty high distortion level. It looks to me like it can do roughly 100 watts per channel for any 2 of the 6 channels at any given time. Above that, sound gets poor quickly. And 130 vs 100 watts is only 1.14 dB, an audible but *small* change in volume.

Answer (score 3):

> The specification says it consumes 320 watts.

I would go with that as a first estimate and, assuming that is a Class A-B type, that the efficiency is about 50 to 60% at maximum volume and so the audio output is about 160 W.

> It also says the continuous power output is 100 W per channel.

You can't get 600 W out for 320 W in so someone is stretching things. Each amplifier may be capable of 100 W but the PSU won't be.

> It also says the RMS power output is 144 W per channel.

RMS isn't applicable to a power measurement. RMS stands for *root mean squared* and is related to the heating power of a waveform. Since \$ P \propto V^2 \$ or \$ P \propto I^2 \$ the squaring has already been done. Power rating should be quoted as the peak power or the average power for a particular test signal - sinewave or a particular piece of music.

> When I advertise this thing, how many watts can I call it? 320 watts? 600 watts? 864 watts?

I would recommend that you say something to the effect, "Fills an 8 m x 5 m room with dance party level music with good bass and without distortion."